# Issue regarding innerHTML showing as Typeerror on the console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started to code, and I followed a tutorial video for a coding in javascript. However, the console shows that I have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at app.js:97." I don't understand why. I checked for typos, but there seemed to be none. I hope you guys know why this error keeps coming up. Thanks.

```js
//items
const menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "buttermilk pancakes",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 15.99,
    img: "./images/item-1.jpeg",
    desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "diner double",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 13.99,
    img: "./images/item-2.jpeg",
    desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "godzilla milkshake",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 6.99,
    img: "./images/item-3.jpeg",
    desc: `ombucha chillwave fanny pack 3 wolf moon street art photo booth before they sold out organic viral.`,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "country delight",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 20.99,
    img: "./images/item-4.jpeg",
    desc: `Shabby chic keffiyeh neutra snackwave pork belly shoreditch. Prism austin mlkshk truffaut, `,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "egg attack",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 22.99,
    img: "./images/item-5.jpeg",
    desc: `franzen vegan pabst bicycle rights kickstarter pinterest meditation farm-to-table 90's pop-up `,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "oreo dream",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 18.99,
    img: "./images/item-6.jpeg",
    desc: `Portland chicharrones ethical edison bulb, palo santo craft beer chia heirloom iPhone everyday`,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "bacon overflow",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 8.99,
    img: "./images/item-7.jpeg",
    desc: `carry jianbing normcore freegan. Viral single-origin coffee live-edge, pork belly cloud bread iceland put a bird `,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "american classic",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 12.99,
    img: "./images/item-8.jpeg",
    desc: `on it tumblr kickstarter thundercats migas everyday carry squid palo santo leggings. Food truck truffaut  `,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: "quarantine buddy",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 16.99,
    img: "./images/item-9.jpeg",
    desc: `skateboard fam synth authentic semiotics. Live-edge lyft af, edison bulb yuccie crucifix microdosing.`,
  },
];

const sectionCenter = document.querySelector("section-center");

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  let displayMenu = menu.map(function (item) {
    // console.log(item);

    return `<article class="menu-item">
          <img src="${item.img}" class="photo" alt=${item.title} />
          <div class="item-info">
            <header>
              <h4>${item.title}</h4>
              <h4 class="price">${item.price}</h4>
            </header>
            <p class="item-text">
              ${item.desc}
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>`;
  });
  displayMenu = displayMenu.join("");
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
});
```

```css
/*
=============== 
Fonts
===============
*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:400,700&display=swap");

/*
=============== 
Variables
===============
*/

:root {
  /* dark shades of primary color*/
  --clr-primary-1: hsl(205, 86%, 17%);
  --clr-primary-2: hsl(205, 77%, 27%);
  --clr-primary-3: hsl(205, 72%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-4: hsl(205, 63%, 48%);
  /* primary/main color */
  --clr-primary-5: #49a6e9;
  /* lighter shades of primary color */
  --clr-primary-6: hsl(205, 89%, 70%);
  --clr-primary-7: hsl(205, 90%, 76%);
  --clr-primary-8: hsl(205, 86%, 81%);
  --clr-primary-9: hsl(205, 90%, 88%);
  --clr-primary-10: hsl(205, 100%, 96%);
  /* darkest grey - used for headings */
  --clr-grey-1: hsl(209, 61%, 16%);
  --clr-grey-2: hsl(211, 39%, 23%);
  --clr-grey-3: hsl(209, 34%, 30%);
  --clr-grey-4: hsl(209, 28%, 39%);
  /* grey used for paragraphs */
  --clr-grey-5: hsl(210, 22%, 49%);
  --clr-grey-6: hsl(209, 23%, 60%);
  --clr-grey-7: hsl(211, 27%, 70%);
  --clr-grey-8: hsl(210, 31%, 80%);
  --clr-grey-9: hsl(212, 33%, 89%);
  --clr-grey-10: hsl(210, 36%, 96%);
  --clr-white: #fff;
  --clr-red-dark: hsl(360, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-red-light: hsl(360, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-green-dark: hsl(125, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-green-light: hsl(125, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-gold: #c59d5f;
  --clr-black: #222;
  --ff-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --ff-secondary: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  --transition: all 0.3s linear;
  --spacing: 0.25rem;
  --radius: 0.5rem;
  --light-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --dark-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --max-width: 1170px;
  --fixed-width: 620px;
}
/*
=============== 
Global Styles
===============
*/

*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-secondary);
  background: var(--clr-grey-10);
  color: var(--clr-grey-1);
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
img:not(.logo) {
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--clr-grey-5);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4 {
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
/*  global classes */

.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--clr-black);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  display: inline-block;
  transition: var(--transition);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border: 2px solid var(--clr-black);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: var(--radius);
}
.btn:hover {
  color: var(--clr-white);
  background: var(--clr-black);
}
/* section */
.section {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
/*
=============== 
Menu
===============
*/

.menu {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.underline {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background: var(--clr-gold);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.btn-container {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.filter-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: var(--clr-gold);
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  color: var(--clr-gold);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: var(--transition);
}
.filter-btn:hover {
  background: var(--clr-gold);
  color: var(--clr-white);
}
.section-center {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 3rem 2rem;
  justify-items: center;
}
.menu-item {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem 2rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}
.photo {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0.25rem solid var(--clr-gold);
  border-radius: var(--radius);
}
.item-info header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 0.5px dotted var(--clr-grey-5);
}
.item-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.price {
  color: var(--clr-gold);
}
.item-text {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .menu-item {
    grid-template-columns: 225px 1fr;
    gap: 0 1.25rem;
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
  .photo {
    height: 175px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .section-center {
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .photo {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Starter</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="menu">
      <!-- title -->
      <div class="title">
        <h2>our menu</h2>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- filter buttons -->
      <!-- menu items -->
      <div class="section-center">
        <!-- single item -->
        <article class="menu-item">
          <img src="./menu-item.jpeg" class="photo" alt="menu item" />
          <div class="item-info">
            <header>
              <h4>butter milk pancakes</h4>
              <h4 class="price">$15</h4>
            </header>
            <p class="item-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae
              quasi provident id eligendi vitae unde odit aperiam quam, expedita
              mollitia.
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
        <!-- end of single item -->
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a dot in the selector:

```
document.querySelector(".section-center")
```

as you are going to get the element by its class

```js
//items
const menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "buttermilk pancakes",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 15.99,
    img: "./images/item-1.jpeg",
    desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "diner double",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 13.99,
    img: "./images/item-2.jpeg",
    desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "godzilla milkshake",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 6.99,
    img: "./images/item-3.jpeg",
    desc: `ombucha chillwave fanny pack 3 wolf moon street art photo booth before they sold out organic viral.`,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "country delight",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 20.99,
    img: "./images/item-4.jpeg",
    desc: `Shabby chic keffiyeh neutra snackwave pork belly shoreditch. Prism austin mlkshk truffaut, `,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "egg attack",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 22.99,
    img: "./images/item-5.jpeg",
    desc: `franzen vegan pabst bicycle rights kickstarter pinterest meditation farm-to-table 90's pop-up `,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "oreo dream",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 18.99,
    img: "./images/item-6.jpeg",
    desc: `Portland chicharrones ethical edison bulb, palo santo craft beer chia heirloom iPhone everyday`,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "bacon overflow",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 8.99,
    img: "./images/item-7.jpeg",
    desc: `carry jianbing normcore freegan. Viral single-origin coffee live-edge, pork belly cloud bread iceland put a bird `,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "american classic",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 12.99,
    img: "./images/item-8.jpeg",
    desc: `on it tumblr kickstarter thundercats migas everyday carry squid palo santo leggings. Food truck truffaut  `,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: "quarantine buddy",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 16.99,
    img: "./images/item-9.jpeg",
    desc: `skateboard fam synth authentic semiotics. Live-edge lyft af, edison bulb yuccie crucifix microdosing.`,
  },
];

const sectionCenter = document.querySelector(".section-center");

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  let displayMenu = menu.map(function (item) {
    // console.log(item);

    return `<article class="menu-item">
          <img src="${item.img}" class="photo" alt=${item.title} />
          <div class="item-info">
            <header>
              <h4>${item.title}</h4>
              <h4 class="price">${item.price}</h4>
            </header>
            <p class="item-text">
              ${item.desc}
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>`;
  });
  displayMenu = displayMenu.join("");
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
});
```

```css
/*
=============== 
Fonts
===============
*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:400,700&display=swap");

/*
=============== 
Variables
===============
*/

:root {
  /* dark shades of primary color*/
  --clr-primary-1: hsl(205, 86%, 17%);
  --clr-primary-2: hsl(205, 77%, 27%);
  --clr-primary-3: hsl(205, 72%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-4: hsl(205, 63%, 48%);
  /* primary/main color */
  --clr-primary-5: #49a6e9;
  /* lighter shades of primary color */
  --clr-primary-6: hsl(205, 89%, 70%);
  --clr-primary-7: hsl(205, 90%, 76%);
  --clr-primary-8: hsl(205, 86%, 81%);
  --clr-primary-9: hsl(205, 90%, 88%);
  --clr-primary-10: hsl(205, 100%, 96%);
  /* darkest grey - used for headings */
  --clr-grey-1: hsl(209, 61%, 16%);
  --clr-grey-2: hsl(211, 39%, 23%);
  --clr-grey-3: hsl(209, 34%, 30%);
  --clr-grey-4: hsl(209, 28%, 39%);
  /* grey used for paragraphs */
  --clr-grey-5: hsl(210, 22%, 49%);
  --clr-grey-6: hsl(209, 23%, 60%);
  --clr-grey-7: hsl(211, 27%, 70%);
  --clr-grey-8: hsl(210, 31%, 80%);
  --clr-grey-9: hsl(212, 33%, 89%);
  --clr-grey-10: hsl(210, 36%, 96%);
  --clr-white: #fff;
  --clr-red-dark: hsl(360, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-red-light: hsl(360, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-green-dark: hsl(125, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-green-light: hsl(125, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-gold: #c59d5f;
  --clr-black: #222;
  --ff-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --ff-secondary: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  --transition: all 0.3s linear;
  --spacing: 0.25rem;
  --radius: 0.5rem;
  --light-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --dark-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --max-width: 1170px;
  --fixed-width: 620px;
}
/*
=============== 
Global Styles
===============
*/

*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-secondary);
  background: var(--clr-grey-10);
  color: var(--clr-grey-1);
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
img:not(.logo) {
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--clr-grey-5);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4 {
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
/*  global classes */

.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--clr-black);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  display: inline-block;
  transition: var(--transition);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border: 2px solid var(--clr-black);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: var(--radius);
}
.btn:hover {
  color: var(--clr-white);
  background: var(--clr-black);
}
/* section */
.section {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
/*
=============== 
Menu
===============
*/

.menu {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.underline {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background: var(--clr-gold);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.btn-container {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.filter-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: var(--clr-gold);
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  color: var(--clr-gold);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: var(--transition);
}
.filter-btn:hover {
  background: var(--clr-gold);
  color: var(--clr-white);
}
.section-center {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 3rem 2rem;
  justify-items: center;
}
.menu-item {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem 2rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}
.photo {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0.25rem solid var(--clr-gold);
  border-radius: var(--radius);
}
.item-info header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 0.5px dotted var(--clr-grey-5);
}
.item-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.price {
  color: var(--clr-gold);
}
.item-text {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .menu-item {
    grid-template-columns: 225px 1fr;
    gap: 0 1.25rem;
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
  .photo {
    height: 175px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .section-center {
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .photo {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Starter</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="menu">
      <!-- title -->
      <div class="title">
        <h2>our menu</h2>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- filter buttons -->
      <!-- menu items -->
      <div class="section-center">
        <!-- single item -->
        <article class="menu-item">
          <img src="./menu-item.jpeg" class="photo" alt="menu item" />
          <div class="item-info">
            <header>
              <h4>butter milk pancakes</h4>
              <h4 class="price">$15</h4>
            </header>
            <p class="item-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae
              quasi provident id eligendi vitae unde odit aperiam quam, expedita
              mollitia.
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
        <!-- end of single item -->
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`const sectionCenter = document.querySelector(".section-center");` is the valid statement since `section-center` is a class. You're trying to access it as a **tag** like `div`.